# Contenteditable div can´t be read by Jquery, variable returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I need to pass the content from a contenteditable div into an input, in order to submit it with PHP.
I found out that Jquery can´t read its content, I'd be thankful if anyone could solve my problem.

```js
function textChange() {
  var str = $('#preblogbody').html();
  $("#blogbody").val(str);
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<form>

.....

<div id="WYSIWYG" id="preblogbody" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="textChange()" onmouseup="textChange()"> 
   </div>
   <textarea class="hidden" id="blogbody"  name="blogbody"></textarea>
      
.....
      
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ID's on the same element. The second one is being ignored.

Change

```
<div id="WYSIWYG" id="preblogbody" contenteditable="true"...
```

To

```
<div id="preblogbody" contenteditable="true"...
```

and your code works fine as shown